# in drupal 7, how can drupal link to another remote service, consume the data in the web service such as nodejs?

Tags: drupal, node.js, remote-server

I am using the drupal 7 for my CMS server, at the same time, I have a nodejs based server, I need the drupal link to my nodejs server in order to make drupal consume the data in the nodejs based server, which  will expose the restful service interface

Is there such a module that could link to the remote web service like nodejs rest, consume the data in the web service and expose the remote data as a view?  and how to establish the authentication between drupal and nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node.js integration](http://drupal.org/project/nodejs) - This module integrates Node.js with Drupal.

[AMQP](http://drupal.org/project/amqp) - AMQP NodeJS - Integrates with a NodeJS server, allowing you to consumer messages in the browser using JavaScript. This is great for notification-type messages.